# What is the way to play Ringtone notification via SoundPool?

Tags: android

User selects a ringtone using RingtonePreference, and I'm able to extract the Uri with:

```
String pathString = mPreferences.getString(sKeySoundRingtone, null);
Uri pathUri;

if (pathString == null)
    pathUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);;
else
    pathUri = Uri.parse(pathString);
```

Now I want to use the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class because I'm only using notifications (usually under 5secs in duration) and I like the loop and rate options it provides.

Tried my best and failed, since the class can be constructed with a path, and pathUri.getPath() doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

When your notification get brodcast you will get any receiver will call. At that time you can simply call the function to play sound from sound pool.

See below:

```
public void Sound(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    android.util.Log.v("SOUND","["+volume+"]["+spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f)+"]");
};
```

Comment: How you create soundID from pathUri?

Comment: soundID =spool.load(audioFile.getAbsolutePath(), 1);

Answer (score 0):

To load a Ringtone in SoundPool, you may use an AssetFileDescriptor in the following way:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0);

ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
try (AssetFileDescriptor afd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ringtoneUri, "r")) {
    soundPool.load(afd, 1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("SOUNDPOOL", "Couldn't open " + (ringtoneUri == null ? "null uri" : ringtoneUri.toString()), e);
}
```